# i want to validate email address from javascript objects

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to validate email address but this code is not working please let me know how to fix this issue.

```
function submitdata() {
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');

    let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    var userObj = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= userObj.length; i++) {

        if (email.value === userObj[i].useremail) {
            alert("already registered")
        }
        else if (user === null) {
            var userObj = [];
        }
        else {
            userObj = JSON.parse(user);
            userObj.push({ useremail: email.value, userpw: password.value })
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userObj));
            email.value = "";
            password.value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var userObj = [];
```

Looks like this is the issue. The length of the `userObj is 0`.

`if (email.value === userObj[i].useremail)`

Here the userObj is empty. The 0th index never there in first place.

I tried to simulate the same case. You should have got error something like this.

```
let users = []

console.log(users[0].email);
VM329:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:10
(anonymous) @ VM329:1
```

Execute this loop only when you have more than one item in your `userObj`

Comment: @Jahanzaib Kindly accept the answer if it helps you ! Thanks